# SSL client certificates / mutual authentication with ServiceStack (HttpListener)

Tags: c#, ssl, servicestack, httplistener

I'm trying to get mutual SSL authentication working with ServiceStack, which under the hood uses `HttpListener`.

I use this command on the server to bind the server certificate to the required port, and enable client certificates:

`netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:1234 certhash=5d51087438cbea33f2a4d86214b11a866876b9c5 appid={00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444} clientcertnegotiation=enable`

If I run this command I can confirm that it says `Negotiate Client Certificate    : Enabled`:

`netsh http show sslcert`

Then I add a reservation for the namespace using:

`netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:1234/ user="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"`

'Normal' server authentication seems to work fine; the client is receiving the server's certificate and I can use `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` to override what is trusted.

But if the client sends no client certificate, it works as normal. If the client sends a client certificate (whether trusted or untrusted by the server), it still works as normal. This is of course not right!

I'm adding the client certificate using `HttpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(X509Certificate)`.

I've taken a look at the traffic on the wire, and AFAICS the server is sending a list of trusted CAs and requesting a client certificate.

Do I need to override something at the server to perform verification of the certificate sent by the client, similar to how clients can use `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` to verify the server certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceStack allows you to configure 'global filters', which can intercept all requests.

I solved my problem using a global filter:

```
public static void Validate(IRequest request, IResponse response, object message)
{
  var httpRequest = ((ListenerRequest)request).HttpRequest;
  var consoleCert = httpRequest.GetClientCertificate();
  ...
```

I can then send 403 if the client certificate is not present or is invalid:

```
response.StatusCode = 403;
response.EndRequest();
return;
```

Not sure if this is the recommended approach (or indeed if there *is* a recommended approach, but it works for me.